# Calling a pure C function from JNI method

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm working on JNi example . I have a C file :

```
#include "test_lib.h"
#include <mobile_crypto.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int mainCrypto(void){
.
.
.
.
return 1 ;
}
```

Now i want to access the mainCrypto() method from another C file where my JNI methods are written :

```
#include "com_My_NativeLib.h"
#include "test_lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_My_NativeLib_crypt(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){


    int status = 0; 
    status = mainCrypto();

    return status;
}
```

I want to know whether i can call pure C function mainCrypto() from another C file in the way i am doing in this example. I'm not getting any return value and therefore status variable value is not getting updated.

Thanks in advance.

Some errors that i'm getting : 
DEBUG/NDK_NativeLib(3640): [ 09-12 15:58:40.766  3640:0xe38 F//system/bin/app_process ]
DEBUG/NDK_NativeLib(3640): stack corruption detected: aborted
DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 3640 terminated by signal (6)
INFO/ActivityManager(41): Process com.crypto(pid 3640) has died.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create h file, for example maincrypto.h with follow text

int mainCrypto(void);

in your cpp file with Java_com_My_NativeLib_crypt add #include "maincrypto.h" and thats all

Comment: @ Henry Pushel:Thank you for your response . I had created the header files as you have suggested. My return statement from mainCrypto() is not getting executed. My Error logs are        DEBUG/NDK_NativeLib(3640): [ 09-12 15:58:40.766  3640:0xe38 F//system/bin/app_process ]
DEBUG/NDK_NativeLib(3640): stack corruption detected: aborted
DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 3640 terminated by signal (6)
INFO/ActivityManager(41): Process com.crypto(pid 3640) has died.

Comment: Looks like error in your code. Defining functions via H file can't be reason of this error. Try to comment all code inside mainCrypto

Answer (score 1):

Why would you think you might not be able to call `mainCrypto()` from some other C function? It seems pretty obvious that there's no reason why you couldn't, however I don't think you would ask the question unless you had reason to think you couldn't. Barring some strange detail you're leaving out, yes, you can call it from other places too.